# Kik Bot | Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a kik bot, but I keep getting this error anytime I try and run it "Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined". I have installed node and the kik package but that seems not to be working here is my Javascript:

```
request.post({
    url: "https://api.kik.com/v1/config",
    auth: {
        user: "<my-user-name>",
        pass: "<my-api-key>"
    },
    json: {
        "webhook": "<link>",
        "features": {
            "receiveReadReceipts": false,
            "receiveIsTyping": false,
            "manuallySendReadReceipts": false,
            "receiveDeliveryReceipts": false
        },
        "staticKeyboard": {
            "type": "suggested",
            "responses": [
                {
                    "body": "Start",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "body": "Help",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}, callback);
```

I've been trying to looking into this but came up with nothing. Could it be a Node problem?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: did you install request? `npm install request` and required it? `var request = require('request');`

Comment: Ok that confuses me, does it have to be in a specific place to run in node. thats all the code the example gave me.

Comment: This is just like a documentation then, not a runnable piece of code. You need to install `request` using npm, then requiring it. and also to modify the code and provide proper callback function.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Yes I did try that but the error still comes up

Comment: What error? `request` or `require`? you have something in the title of your question and another thing inside the body of it.

Comment: Now I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127330/discussion-between-a-and-scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the conversation we had, I thought I put the answer here for future references.

That piece of code is supposed to be run on NodeJS in commandline, not a browser.

You need to setup a node environment, install the required dependencies using npm or whatever you like. Then run the code in node.

`$ npm install request` to install request.
`var request = require('request')` to require the installed library.

Also you need to modify the code and provide proper a callback function. You can read requests documentation [here](https://github.com/request/request).